# how to find the maximum occurence of a string in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

i have 2 columns in a table. Data looks like this

```
Folio_no | Flag
1145       R

201        S

1145       FR

300        E

1145       R

201        E

201        S
```

```
Expected Output:

Folio_No | Flag

1145        R

201         S

300         E
```

The output should give the folio_no along with the flag which occured maximum number of times for that particular folio number.

i tried doing the below but it throws an error

select folio_no, max(count(flag)) from table group by folio_no;

Comment: Your title says oracle while the tag says sql-server. These are different products.

Comment: I am trying to do this in Oracle SQL developer

Comment: That still does not explains why you ask oracle questions in a sql-server forum. You do now they both have nothing to do with each other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an aggregation:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Folio_No, Flag, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Folio_No, Flag
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Folio_No ORDER BY cnt DESC, Flag) rnk
    FROM cte t
)

SELECT Folio_No, Flag
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that I assume should two flags within a given folio number be tied for the max frequency, that you want to report the earlier flag.

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=955d010c7e54a62d56b0ab906b09d768).

Comment: No i want to report a flag which occurs maximum number of times. If i have 1000 entries for a folio number , there will be multiple flags reported. I need just one entry for that folio number with a flag which occured maximum number of times. Out of 1000 entries if the flag comes 800 times then that should be the flag which needs to be present corresponding to the folio number

Comment: Did you check the demo link I gave above?  My answer generates exactly the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the flag(s) that have the maximum occurrence for each folio then you can use:

```sql
SELECT Folio_No, Flag
FROM   (
  SELECT Folio_No,
         Flag,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Folio_No ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY Folio_No, Flag
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (folio_no, flag) AS
  SELECT 1145, 'R'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201,  'S'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1145, 'FR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 300,  'E'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1145, 'R'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201,  'E'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201,  'S'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201,  'S'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  'A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  'A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  'B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  'B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  'D'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FOLIO_NO | FLAG |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A |
> | 1 | B |
> | 201 | S |
> | 300 | E |
> | 1145 | R |

---

If you want only a single flag with the maximum occurrence for each folio, and if there are ties then the first folio alphabetically in each folio, then:

```sql
SELECT Folio_No, Flag
FROM   (
  SELECT Folio_No,
         Flag,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Folio_No ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, flag) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY Folio_No, Flag
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data outputs:

> | FOLIO_NO | FLAG |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A |
> | 201 | S |
> | 300 | E |
> | 1145 | R |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3f17f0d2e54a5a8e2c534842b609872b)*